# why is there a data latency between amazon seller central and amazon advertising api?

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I have been using the amazon advertising api to fetch my client's the seller central data. I've observed that there is always a deviation in metrics data when comparing the API response with the amazon seller central interface.

Note: The API response has less data when compared to the interface.

Please let me know how to address this issue, or the reason for the data latency.